# SpecFlow Exception, while running a test under WP8 project

Tags: windows-phone-8, specflow, vs-unit-testing-framework

Trying to run SpecFlow test I receive an error:

```
Missing resource DefaultSkeletonTemplates.sftemplates
```

I have:

- The feature file
- Feature class (generated code)
- Feature step
- All classes bound

What could be the problem?

Comment: How are you running the test? (Reshaper test runner/VS2012 runner/Right-click Run tests)?? Have you got Specflow's VS plugin installed or just picked up Specflow via NuGet? Which version of VS are you running? Where does the error appear (Can we have a bit of context please?) Are you referencing SpecFlow in your test assembly?

Comment: the project is Windows Phone, I'm running this on VS 12, with specFlow from NuGet, and using Test Explorer.. the thing is SpecFlow does not support my project,.. further investigation has led me to believe that my Feature Class (auto generated code), is corrupted.. and am not sure how to fix it.. since as I mentioned SpecFlow does not support windows phone, I generate the code under under VS 13 windows project and copy it into mine.. Am I Clear ?              participation is much appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue when the step isn't defined or can't be found.

You can run the test using statlight.exe on the command line to see SpecFlow's detailed output on the console.

In the feature file, right-click on the step and select "Go To Step Definition".

If a step can't be found, a message appears with the text "No matching step binding found for this step! Do you want to copy the step binding skeleton to the clipboard?"

Select Yes to copy the code for the step to the clipboard.

Then paste the code in a SpecFlow bound class and try running the scenario again.